# How do you remove illegal characters from an xml file?

Tags: xml, encoding, character-encoding

I am using the PHP SimpleXML way of working with XML files on my server. I only need to read the contents of the XML (I have no need to modify it) so I stuck to the simple and easy to use SimpleXML. But SimpleXML is having problems reading a certain XML file because it has some very strange characters. I get the following errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: data/data.xml:348: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\VMP\xintel\analyzer.php on line 54

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: Jardin al fte. Hall de recepcion, amplio living comedor. ocina comedor diario c in C:\xampp\htdocs\VMP\xintel\analyzer.php on line 54
```

I have no control of what goes into the XML file, so I can't stop these characters from being added to the file. Also, I don't know how to solve this issue. The file is supposed to be encoded in utf-8. So I tried things like decoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 and the reverse, but nothing is happening.

Can somebody help me out? Should I try to change the encoding? Should I try to remove those characters? Anything?

Edit: The stangre characters are all box-drawing characters (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters)

Comment: If the file contains illegal XML characters, then it's not an XML file, and using an XML parser will not help you.

Comment: Well, I can see that the illegal characters crash the xml parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an app that receives XML from untrusted sources, many of which send me unencoded ampersands.  To solve the problem, I have an intermediate filter that does a single linear pass and gets rid of / encodes characters where necessary.  I don't know if that is possible for you but I think it's a pretty reasonable solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. But I am not sure how to do that. Does your app change the encoding or does it  actually replace problematic characters with character encodings?

Comment: Sorry, when I said "encodes" I wasn't referring to the charset.  As an example, in the case of a raw ampersand it will be replaced with &amp; -- then, you need to make sure this ampersand is not already part of a valid encoding, OR do a decoding pass when processing is done.

Comment: I think that is what I will do. What would be best though is a way to re-encode the whole xml file so that in the future the script does not crash when it encounters a character I can not checked for.

Comment: Of course, this filter step doesn't have to be done entirely in memory. You could overwrite the XML on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could pass the input through [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to make it well-formed. One simple step of pre-processing before you feed the file to SimpleXML.

For example, [`tidy::repairFile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairfile.php) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all character of an XML file are interpreted unless they are into a CDATA section => [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp)

If it not the case your XML is invalid.

Comment: The question is how to handle such an invalid XML file when it's not under your control.

Comment: I can say for sure that all the text in the xml is placed in CDATA blocks. So all these characters are found within CDATA.

Comment: Well, yes, but Like I said in a previous comment, I can't even paste in the strange characters.

Comment: You can't provide a file somewhere ?